# How to enable Change Sets in Eclipse Mars?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-mars

I am trying to configure a new version of Eclipse and I cannot figure out how to get the "Show Change Sets" icon to show up on the Team Synchronize perspective. It looks like Mylyn comes with Mars and I even tried to install the mylyn Task List feature from "Mylyn for Eclipse Mars-http://download.eclipse.org/mylyn/releases/mars" but was told that was down level.
I also installed "Mylyn Tasks Connector: Trac". I have my Jira task list working fine but I can see no way to either create a new local task or assign any of my changes to an existing task.

This is a hugely important feature for me as I have lots of local changes I do not want to be checking in and I also want to bulk check in a group of related changes against specific jiras.

Comment: I also installed Subclipse and still no change sets.

Answer (score 0):

They hid the change sets switch in the little pull down two to the right of the synchronize pull down on the Team Synchronizing perspective.